# How to Connect two php form files, with the same id and save their data together in the database:

Tags: php, html

I have a system which has only two transaction, Registration.php and req.php. The two transaction data are saved in the table new in my database. Registration.php is my first transacton, then req.php. This php files are form, which both has a submit button linked to add.php. The fields of my new table are devided in the two forms. The flow is that first Registration.php will be executed then req.php. My table new has a primary key named new_id and its auto increment. My problem is that, after execution of both forms, ONLY the data of Registration.php are save in the database table new and the req.php are blank. What is the problem? I need your help.

here is the Registration.php code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js">

</script>
<TITLE>
        New Registration Form
    </TITLE></head>

<body>
<center>
<br>
<p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 30">Please Fill Out Your Information Sheet</p><p><?php                      
                        echo date('F j, Y, g:i a', time()+25200);
                        ?></p>
<form method="POST" action="add.php">
<!--<input type="text" name="new_fname" class="Form-Control" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" required>-->
<input type="text" name="new_fname" class="Form-Control" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" required>
<input type="text" name="new_mname" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Middle Initial" id="mname" required>
<input type="text" name="new_lname" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" required><br><br>
Select Your gender
<select name="new_gender">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>

Select Your Status

<select name="new_status">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="New">New</option>
    <option value="Old">Old</option>
    <option value="Transferee">Transferee</option>
    <option value="Shiftee">Shiftee</option>
</select>

Select Your Course

<select name="new_course">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="BSINFOTECH">BSINFOTECH</option>
    <option value="BSIS">BSIS</option>
    <option value="BSCOMTECH">BSCOMTECH</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_age" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Age" id="age" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_bp" class="Form-Control"  placeholder="Birth Place" id="bp" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_add" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Address" id="add" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_nat" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Nationality" id="nat" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_rel" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Religion" id="rel" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_tel" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Tel. No." id="tel" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_cel" class="Form-Control" placeholder="Cel. No." id="cel" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="new_mail" class="Form-Control" placeholder="E-mail Address" id="mail" required><br><br>
    <button onclick="parent.location='req.php'" type="submit" name="next">Next</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="save" value="save">Save</button>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the req.php code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js">

</script>
<title>
REQUIRMENTS FORM    
</title>
<br>
<p align="center" style="font-size: 50">REQUIRMENTS FORM</p> 
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br>
<p align="center" style="font-size: 30">Registrar</p>
<form style="font-size: 20" action="add.php" method='post'>
 Form 138
<br>
<select name="form1">
<option value=""</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
Form 137A
<br>
<select name="form2">
<option value=""</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
2 X 2 ID
<br>
<select name="picture">
<option value=""</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
NSO Birth Certificate
<br>
<select name="nso">
<option value=""</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
Good Moral Certificate
<br>
<select name="gmc">
<option value=""</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<p align="center" style="font-size: 30">Library</p>
Library Card
<br>
<select name="lc">
<option value=""</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<p align="center" style="font-size: 30">Cashier</p>
<p><h4>You should have paid minimum of P2000.00-2500.00</h4></p>
<input type="text" name="cashier" class="Form-Control" width="100px" placeholder="Enter amount" id="cashier" required></input>
<button type="submit" style="font-size: 20" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" value="save">SUBMIT</button>
<button  type="button" style="font-size: 20" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><a href="newform.php?id=<?php echo $data->new_id ?>">Process Student Copy</button>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data->new_id ?>" name="id" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the add.php code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("enrollee");
$course=$_POST['new_course'];
$gender=$_POST['new_gender'];
$gender=$_POST['new_gender'];
$status=$_POST['new_status'];
$fname=$_POST['new_fname'];
$mname=$_POST['new_mname'];
$lname=$_POST['new_lname'];
$age=$_POST['new_age'];
$bp=$_POST['new_bp'];
$add=$_POST['new_add'];
$nat=$_POST['new_nat'];
$rel=$_POST['new_rel'];
$tel=$_POST['new_tel'];
$cel=$_POST['new_cel'];
$mail=$_POST['new_mail'];
form1=$_POST['form1'];
$form2=$_POST['form2'];
$picture=$_POST['picture'];
$nso=$_POST['nso'];
$gmc=$_POST['gmc'];
$lc=$_POST['lc'];
$cashier=$_POST['cashier'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO new(new_id,new_course,new_gender,new_status,new_fname,new_mname,new_lname,new_age,new_bp,new_add,new_nat,new_rel,new_tel,new_cel,new_mail,form1,form2,picture,nso,gmc,lc,cashier))
                VALUES(NULL, '$course','$gender', '$status', '$fname','$mname','$lname','$age','$bp','$add','$nat','$rel','$tel','$cel','$mail','$form1','$form2','$picture','$nso','$gmc','$lc','$cashier')");         
    header("Location: read.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: Can we see some code please, difficult to help you debug when we don't know what is happening.

Comment: you will have to give us some of your code, it could be any number of issues

Comment: id should be unique for entire document ..

Comment: Paste your code to get help. *No One is going to assume your code.*

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm just new year. Thank you for replies. new table has a primary key I named new_id which is auto increment. Then Registration.php is executed first, then req.php. each of them has a submit button link to add.php. Is this the reason why only Registration.php data are saved and not the req.data? Because in the add.php. all of the table fields are there, both of Registration and req. but I seperated asking their data in two forms which is the Registration.php and req.php. Please, help me. I really need your help guys.

Comment: You need to add the code to your question by using the [edit] link below it. That way you can properly *format* the code so that people can read it. Add the text information from your comment, as well, so that everything is in one place when people look at the question.

Comment: Guys, please help. What is wrong or lacking in my code?

Answer (score 0):

When you save the data into the database, you probably have one field that is `primary key` and `auto increment`, right? *(if not, you should - label it ID or registration_id or some such)*

On the `req.php` page, you should begin by reading the database - something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new");
```

That will give you a MySQL resource containing all the fields in all the rows. You must then get each row, something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
    echo $row['first_name'];
}
```

Use the above methodology to build your `req.php` page, containing the data you stored from `registration.php` page.

It may be helpful to you to do the `Registration and Login` tutorial over at [codecourse.com](http://codecourse.com), or to do a number of the PHP tutorials over at [thenewboston](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=92)

---

It might help you to know that you can [get the ID of the last inserted row](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp).

You can then use that ID to `UPDATE` (instead of `INSERT`) the data from the req.php file.

```
UPDATE `new` SET `fieldname` = '$value', `nuthername` = '$nextval' WHERE `new_id` = '$last_inserted_id'
```

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm just new year. Thank you for replies. new table has a primary key I named new_id which is auto increment. Then Registration.php is executed first, then req.php. each of them has a submit button link to add.php. Is this the reason why only Registration.php data are saved and not the req.data? Because in the add.php. all of the table fields are there, both of Registration and req. but I seperated asking their data in two forms which is the Registration.php and req.php. Please, help me. I really need your help guys. How could I save both their data in their corresponding fields.

Comment: You may wait hours for an answer that you can use. However, if you do the Register & Login tutorial over at TNB (linked in my answer), you will know how to do it yourself after one or two hours. It will be faster to learn from the videos.

Comment: Yes, I have the primary key which is new_id and its auto increment. This is my project. I have a system called enrollment flow system. I have 2 transaction only that is Registration and req.php. Its just a simple system. but my problem is that only the Registration.php data are save. Registration is first executed then req.php. All their data are ment to be save in the new table in my database. But sadly only Registration data are saved and req data are blank. Please, I need your help. I want after the two transaction, all of the data are seen in the table new.

Comment: See addition to question. Best I can do for you. Watch the tutorials.

Comment: Guys, please help. What is wrong or lacking in my code?